# Where can I get a piano/music teacher certification?

Tags: piano

For a person who has a Masters Degree in Piano Performance and also has a few years of teaching experience, what is a good place to get some sort of teaching certification that is accepted worldwide, preferably online. Now, I know this might not be the right place to ask this question... but maybe someone knows the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any online certifications, but ABRSM (Associated Board of the Royal Schools of Music) do offer teaching diplomas.

https://us.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/diplomas/instrumentalvocal-teaching/

This is the US site, but most of their exams are available in many countries and you will be able to find country-specific information on their website.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it's possible to get a teacher's degree online, cause you know, it's all about the practical stuff. As far as I know, you're only able to get a teacher's degree by doing it as a minor course during your bachelor/master, or do a post-degree teacher's course at a music college.

Note: this is how it works in the Netherlands, might be different around the world.